# html how to fade input textfield

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery api to fade the input, as shown below:

```
$(#input).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
```

and input in html is

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
```

It works. However, how can I fade this input once the page is loaded or just opened?

Comment: `$(#input)` must be properly quoted. For example: `$("#input")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it in DOM Ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwd0xxb/)

Comment: thanks, it works. is there any particular attributes for input which may result same effects?

Comment: I would actually use `$(window).on('load',function(...`, that way the fade starts when all the elements have actually loaded (otherwise you might miss (part of) the fade)

Comment: @myfunkyside that is only triggered when all resources(images, videos, external js, css) are loaded. It isn't needed in this case

Comment: something like <input type="text" name="input" id="input" disabled="">, which disable attributes disable input. so is there a attribute for fading?

Comment: @user3764319 nope.. you can however do it in css, however that's a separate question

Comment: @AmitJoki - So if he has a site with a lot of pictures on it that need to be loaded, this fade would happen during that loading process right, whilst images are being loaded and the site is building itself up, not yet displayed in its final fully loaded state?

Answer (score 1):

Pure css [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymvsvm2k/) this way even if the user has Javascript deactivated it will work and you don't need to set you input to `display:none`

Markup

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
```

Style

```
#input{
    animation:fadeIn 3s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from{opacity:0}
  to{opacity:.5}
}
```

Comment: But, the chances of them having JS enabled are more than the possibility of their browser supporting the CSS IMO. They are good points though.

Comment: I wouldn't call a webkit-only solution "pure css". Plus OP is wanting fade from 1 to .5, not 0 to 1.

Comment: @Anthony That that is up to you but i wouldn't use js where i can use css, css is a way far better for performance as js

Comment: I think you meant that for @EternalHour, +1 for updating per my comment

Comment: @Tambo I agree, +1 for providing a more universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs205fkr/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#input').hide();
   $('#input').fadeIn(5000);
)};
```